# WebResource put removes the '+' character of the requestEntity

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I have a client WebService that uses the jersey.api and communicates with another application RESTful.
I send the json data from the javascript to the client and it sends to the application "server".

The problem is, when I recieve the data from client, the characters '+' are there and when I execute the method put to send the request to server it's there too. But when I get the UriInfo (In the "server" WS) and look the request properties, the '+' characters disappears.

I've tried to debug my application to find bugs but seems that the error is in some conversion of parameters on jersey side.

Anyone could help me?

```
case PUT:
   response = resource.accept(types).entity(requestEntity, entityContentType).put(String.class);
   break;
```

Thats the method that sends the request to server.

```
@PUT
    @Consumes( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Path("method/{param}/{p}")
    public WSResponse method(@Context UriInfo info,
```

How I recieve the request on "server"

Comment: + in urlencode text mean whitespace

Comment: Expanding on @talex' comment: you'd need to encode the `+` characters, e.g. by replacing them with `%2B` on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to URL encode that symbol because `+` is taken as space. The correct URL encoding for a literal plus sign is `%2B`. You should probably use a utility like [URLCodec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/URLCodec.html) from [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).